# How to Get More Tutoring Clients & Grow?

Tags: computer-science, tutoring

I'm a student, and I've been tutoring in Computer Science for roughly a year. I've been studying computer science and doing projects for fun for about 3 years. For most of my time tutoring, I've made the occasional post in communities on certain apps like Discord, offering my services and a brief description. (obviously, posting where permitted) I've been a member in some decent communities, which has been netting me a few clients, especially in the past months with the start of many fall semesters.

However, I'm looking to grow beyond this in terms of the number of clients I reach. I've considered putting up advertisements (if you would call them that) around my school, but other than that, what could I do? Should I consider pushing further for online growth, or look at in-person options? (as mentioned above) Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to grow your business ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tutor, and it's a lot of fun, but you have to market yourself. Using social media is essential for anyone trying to generate serious business nowadays, whether it is a one-person home-business or a large corporation.

You should not compete on price. You will never be as cheap as a student who is still supported by loans or his parents. You will also get the type of clients you deserve for that price.

Concentrate your services. What classes do you teach? Which age groups/school types are appropriate? This makes it easier for you to gain an advantage in the subject matter, develop teaching materials, and so on.

Request recommendations and testimonials. In the tutoring world, word of mouth is extremely powerful. Children and students converse with their classmates, and parents converse with one another.